# http-on-examine-response observer - possible to block response from further processing?

Tags: firefox, xpcom

I am attempting to implement a firefox extension which filters incoming HTTP responses and handles them accordingly.

I wish to block HTTP responses containing a specific header. Having read through some of the MDC articles, it appears the most common way of observing HTTP responses is by registering an http-on-examine-response observer.

My question is: Using this observer, is it possible to block the HTTP request from further processing (as a by-product, the page will continue to wait for a response)? Or do I need to use some other facet of XPCOM (if so, care to point me in the right direction)?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be possible: the "subject" of that notification is a HTTP channel, on which you can call nsIRequest::cancel().

the page will **not** continue to wait for a response, though, since you blocked the response. Perhaps you've been actually looking for a way to [alter an HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695440/altering-http-responses-in-firefox-extension)?