# Altering HTTP Responses in Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

How can I alter the HTTP response body in a Firefox extension? I have setup an http-on-examine-response observer and an nsIStreamListener object with the code below. After I get the data, parse it, and alter it, how do I push the altered response back to the firefox browser? For example, let's say I go to Google.com with my extension enabled, the extension should intercept the response and change every occurence of "google" to "goggle". So when the page is loaded, the user will see "goggle" everywhere.

```
function TmSteroidsObserver()
{
  this.register();
}


TmSteroidsObserver.prototype = {
  observe: function(subject, topic, data) {

    if (topic == "http-on-examine-response") {

    }
    else if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {
       var channel = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIChannel);
       var listener = new StreamListener(channel);
    }

  },

  register: function() {
    var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
    observerService.addObserver(listener, "http-on-modify-request", false);
    observerService.addObserver(listener, "http-on-examine-response", false);
  },

  unregister: function() {
    var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
    observerService.removeObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request");
    observerService.removeObserver(this, "http-on-examine-response");
  },

  QueryInterface : function(aIID) {
    if (aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports) ||
        aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIObserver))
      return this;
    throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
  }

}

function StreamListener(channel) {

    channel.notificationCallbacks = listener;
    channel.asyncOpen(listener, null);

}

StreamListener.prototype = {
  mData: "",
  mChannel: null,

  // nsIStreamListener
  onStartRequest: function (aRequest, aContext) {
    this.mData = "";
  },

  onDataAvailable: function (aRequest, aContext, aStream, aSourceOffset, aLength) {
    var scriptableInputStream = 
      Components.classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);
    scriptableInputStream.init(aStream);

    this.mData += scriptableInputStream.read(aLength);
  },

  onStopRequest: function (aRequest, aContext, aStatus) {
    if (Components.isSuccessCode(aStatus)) {
      // request was successfull
      this.mCallbackFunc(this.mData);
    } else {
      // request failed
      this.mCallbackFunc(null);
    }

    this.mChannel = null;
  },

  // nsIChannelEventSink
  onChannelRedirect: function (aOldChannel, aNewChannel, aFlags) {
    // if redirecting, store the new channel
    this.mChannel = aNewChannel;
  },

  // nsIInterfaceRequestor
  getInterface: function (aIID) {
    try {
      return this.QueryInterface(aIID);
    } catch (e) {
      throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    }
  },

  // nsIProgressEventSink (not implementing will cause annoying exceptions)
  onProgress : function (aRequest, aContext, aProgress, aProgressMax) { },
  onStatus : function (aRequest, aContext, aStatus, aStatusArg) { },

  // nsIHttpEventSink (not implementing will cause annoying exceptions)
  onRedirect : function (aOldChannel, aNewChannel) { },

  // we are faking an XPCOM interface, so we need to implement QI
  QueryInterface : function(aIID) {
    if (aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports) ||
        aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor) ||
        aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIChannelEventSink) || 
        aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIProgressEventSink) ||
        aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpEventSink) ||
        aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIStreamListener))
      return this;

    throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use nsITraceableChannel to intercept the response.

You should modify the data which is available to what you need and pass it to the innerListener's OnDataAvailable

Below links would help you understand this better.

http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/

http://www.ashita.org/howto-xhr-listening-by-a-firefox-addon/

Answer (score 7):

For future readers looking for a way to do this in Firefox Quantum, there is [an API that lets you filter responses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData). Using the method for long documents [mentioned here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/StreamFilter/ondata), I was able to reliably change what I needed in my (temporary) plugin's `background.js` like so:

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function fixenator(details) {
        let filter = browser.webRequest.filterResponseData(details.requestId);
        let decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
        let encoder = new TextEncoder();
        let str = '';

        filter.ondata = event => {
            str += decoder.decode(event.data, {stream: true});
        };

        filter.onstop = event => {
            str = str.replace(/searchPattern/g, 'replace pattern');
            filter.write(encoder.encode(str));
            filter.close();
        }

        return {};
    },
    {
        urls: ['https://example.com/path/to/url']
        //, types: ['main_frame', 'script', 'sub_frame', 'xmlhttprequest', 'other'] // optional
    }
    , ['blocking']
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The observer service just call your listeners. Firefox will receive the requests,call your listeners, and send responses. see Mozilla docs [Creating HTTP POSTs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_Sandboxed_HTTP_Connections#Creating_HTTP_POSTs).