# Read HTTP response from firefox extension

Tags: javascript, http, firefox-addon, request, response

Completly new to firefox extensions. I can't seem to find much information on reading the HTTP response, is it possible?

Anyone have any ideas? I just need to validate it before doing a redirect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Altering HTTP Responses in Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695440/altering-http-responses-in-firefox-extension) and sources of [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/af/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) FireFox extension.