# How can I get the SSL Certificate info for the *current* page in a Firefox Add On

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-5

I'm trying to develop a Firefox extension/add-on that needs access to the SSL Certificate information of the page that is currently loaded.  Once I have this information I plan on modifying the contents of the page based on the SSL information.  Though, before I get there I first need to get the SSL info.

The approach outlined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/How_to_check_the_security_state_of_an_XMLHTTPRequest_over_SSL) makes a separate XMLHTTPRequest to get the security certificate.  I would rather not do that if I could avoid it because it presents a security problem.

For example, a malicious site/man-in-the-middle could provide one certificate on the first request for the page (which the browser would verify) and then provide another certificate for the XMLHTTPRequest that my extension would make.  This would result in the extension modifying site contents based on inconsistent information.  Hence, I'd like to get the SSL Cert information that the browser itself used when verifying the site.

With that in mind I combined the above approach with the method outlined in [Altering HTTP Responses in Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695440/altering-http-responses-in-firefox-extension) to intercept all the HTTP responses by adding an observer of the "http-on-examine-response" event.  I thought that with this method I could simply grab the cert info as it was being downloaded from the site.

Here is the meat of my code, much of it taken from the above links (the rest is Firefox extension boilerplate):

```
function dumpSecurityInfo(channel) {

    const Cc = Components.classes
    const Ci = Components.interfaces;

    // Do we have a valid channel argument?
    if (! channel instanceof  Ci.nsIChannel) {
        dump("No channel available\n");
        return;
    }

    var secInfo = channel.securityInfo;


    // Print general connection security state

    if (secInfo instanceof Ci.nsITransportSecurityInfo) {
        dump("name: " + channel.name + "\n");
        secInfo.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITransportSecurityInfo);

        dump("\tSecurity state: ");

        // Check security state flags
        if ((secInfo.securityState & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_SECURE) == Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_SECURE)
            dump("secure\n");

        else if ((secInfo.securityState & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_INSECURE) == Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_INSECURE)
            dump("insecure\n");

        else if ((secInfo.securityState & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_BROKEN) == Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_BROKEN)
            dump("unknown\n");

        dump("\tSecurity description: " + secInfo.shortSecurityDescription + "\n");
        dump("\tSecurity error message: " + secInfo.errorMessage + "\n");
    }

    // Print SSL certificate details
    if (secInfo instanceof Ci.nsISSLStatusProvider) {

        var cert = secInfo.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISSLStatusProvider).
        SSLStatus.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISSLStatus).serverCert;

        dump("\nCertificate Status:\n");

        var verificationResult = cert.verifyForUsage(Ci.nsIX509Cert.CERT_USAGE_SSLServer);
        dump("\tVerification: ");

        switch (verificationResult) {
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.VERIFIED_OK:
                dump("OK");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.NOT_VERIFIED_UNKNOWN:
                dump("not verfied/unknown");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.CERT_REVOKED:
                dump("revoked");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.CERT_EXPIRED:
                dump("expired");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.CERT_NOT_TRUSTED:
                dump("not trusted");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.ISSUER_NOT_TRUSTED:
                dump("issuer not trusted");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.ISSUER_UNKNOWN:
                dump("issuer unknown");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.INVALID_CA:
                dump("invalid CA");
                break;
            default:
                dump("unexpected failure");
                break;
        }
        dump("\n");

        dump("\tCommon name (CN) = " + cert.commonName + "\n");
        dump("\tOrganisation = " + cert.organization + "\n");
        dump("\tIssuer = " + cert.issuerOrganization + "\n");
        dump("\tSHA1 fingerprint = " + cert.sha1Fingerprint + "\n");

        var validity = cert.validity.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIX509CertValidity);
        dump("\tValid from " + validity.notBeforeGMT + "\n");
        dump("\tValid until " + validity.notAfterGMT + "\n");
    }
}

function TracingListener() {
}

TracingListener.prototype =
{
    originalListener: null,

    onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) {
        try
        {
            dumpSecurityInfo(request)
            this.originalListener.onDataAvailable(request, context, inputStream, offset, count);
        } catch (err) {
            dump(err);
            if (err instanceof Ci.nsIException) 
            {
                request.cancel(e.result);
            }
        }
    },

    onStartRequest: function(request, context) {
        try
        {
            dumpSecurityInfo(request)
            this.originalListener.onStartRequest(request, context);
        } catch (err) {
            dump(err);
            if (err instanceof Ci.nsIException) 
            {
                request.cancel(e.result);
            }
        }
    },

    onStopRequest: function(request, context, statusCode) {
        this.originalListener.onStopRequest(request, context, statusCode);
    },

    QueryInterface: function (aIID) {
        const Ci = Components.interfaces;
        if ( iid.equals(Ci.nsIObserver) ||
             iid.equals(Ci.nsISupportsWeakReference)         ||
             iid.equals(Ci.nsISupports))
        {
            return this;
        }
        throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    }
}


var httpRequestObserver =
{
    observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData)
    {
        const Ci = Components.interfaces;
        if (aTopic == "http-on-examine-response")
        {
            var newListener = new TracingListener();
            aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITraceableChannel);
            newListener.originalListener = aSubject.setNewListener(newListener);
        }
    },

    QueryInterface : function (aIID)
    {
        const Ci = Components.interfaces;
        if (aIID.equals(Ci.nsIObserver) ||
            aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports))
        {
            return this;
        }

        throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;

    }
};

var test =
{
    run: function() {
        const Ci = Components.interfaces;
        dump("run");
        var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
            .getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);    
        observerService.addObserver(httpRequestObserver,
            "http-on-examine-response", false);
    }
};

window.addEventListener("load", function () { test.run(); }, false);
```

What I found is that this implementation is inconsistent.  When I load gmail.com in Firefox I'll sometimes get the certificate information and sometimes I won't.  I suspect this is a caching issue as refreshing the page will usually result in the certificate information being downloaded/printed.

For my intended application this behavior is not acceptable. This is for a research project so, if I have to, I would be willing to modify the Firefox source code, but my preference would be to do this using the extension/add-on API.

Is there a better, more consistent way to get the SSL Certificate information?

Comment: You should not swallow errors in your `TracingListener`. I used to do this and noticed that it causes crashes due to inconsistent state. If the original listener throws an error and you don't want to keep it (due to Error Console spam) then the request needs to be canceled. Like this: `catch (e if e instanceof Ci.nsIException) {request.cancel(e.result);}`

Comment: I made some edits to the question per your suggestion.  Does that handle the case you describe?

Comment: Yes, this way it should work correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Within a web browser, is it possible for JavaScript to obtain information about the SSL Certificate being used for the current page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402121/within-a-web-browser-is-it-possible-for-javascript-to-obtain-information-about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you query the channel to get its security info seems sane. I suspect that your problem is actually timing - you query it at the wrong time. Tracing all requests is really the wrong approach if security info is all you are interested in. It makes far more sense to register a progress listener (there are [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners)) and to look at the channel whenever `onSecurityChange` is being called. You are likely to be only interested in requests where `aState` contains [`STATE_IS_SECURE` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebProgressListener#State_security_flags). Note that `aRequest` parameter is usually an `nsIChannel` instance but could also be a plain `nsIRequest` - `instanceof` check is required.

Comment: Note `onSecurityChange` is now a legacy API and no longer works in current Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners

Comment: @mikemaccana: Pretty much everything is now a legacy API and no longer works. Any pre-2017 information on Firefox add-ons is obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

Building on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983401/how-can-i-get-the-ssl-certificate-info-for-the-current-page-in-a-firefox-extens/6995834#6995834) answer:

The trick is to register a [progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) and check `aState` when the `onSecurityChange` function is called.  If the `Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_SECURE` flag is set then the page is using an SSL connection.  That isn't enough however, the `aRequest` parameter may not be an instance of `Ci.nsIChannel`, that should be verified first with `if (aRequest instanceof Ci.nsIChannel)`.

Here is the working code:

```
function dumpSecurityInfo(channel) {

    const Cc = Components.classes
    const Ci = Components.interfaces;

    // Do we have a valid channel argument?
    if (! channel instanceof  Ci.nsIChannel) {
        dump("No channel available\n");
        return;
    }

    var secInfo = channel.securityInfo;

    // Print general connection security state
    if (secInfo instanceof Ci.nsITransportSecurityInfo) {
        dump("name: " + channel.name + "\n");
        secInfo.QueryInterface(Ci.nsITransportSecurityInfo);

        dump("\tSecurity state: ");

        // Check security state flags
        if ((secInfo.securityState & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_SECURE) == Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_SECURE)
            dump("secure\n");

        else if ((secInfo.securityState & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_INSECURE) == Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_INSECURE)
            dump("insecure\n");

        else if ((secInfo.securityState & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_BROKEN) == Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_BROKEN)
            dump("unknown\n");

        dump("\tSecurity description: " + secInfo.shortSecurityDescription + "\n");
        dump("\tSecurity error message: " + secInfo.errorMessage + "\n");
    }
    else {

        dump("\tNo security info available for this channel\n");
    }

    // Print SSL certificate details
    if (secInfo instanceof Ci.nsISSLStatusProvider) {

        var cert = secInfo.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISSLStatusProvider).
        SSLStatus.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISSLStatus).serverCert;

        dump("\nCertificate Status:\n");

        var verificationResult = cert.verifyForUsage(Ci.nsIX509Cert.CERT_USAGE_SSLServer);
        dump("\tVerification: ");

        switch (verificationResult) {
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.VERIFIED_OK:
                dump("OK");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.NOT_VERIFIED_UNKNOWN:
                dump("not verfied/unknown");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.CERT_REVOKED:
                dump("revoked");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.CERT_EXPIRED:
                dump("expired");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.CERT_NOT_TRUSTED:
                dump("not trusted");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.ISSUER_NOT_TRUSTED:
                dump("issuer not trusted");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.ISSUER_UNKNOWN:
                dump("issuer unknown");
                break;
            case Ci.nsIX509Cert.INVALID_CA:
                dump("invalid CA");
                break;
            default:
                dump("unexpected failure");
                break;
        }
        dump("\n");

        dump("\tCommon name (CN) = " + cert.commonName + "\n");
        dump("\tOrganisation = " + cert.organization + "\n");
        dump("\tIssuer = " + cert.issuerOrganization + "\n");
        dump("\tSHA1 fingerprint = " + cert.sha1Fingerprint + "\n");

        var validity = cert.validity.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIX509CertValidity);
        dump("\tValid from " + validity.notBeforeGMT + "\n");
        dump("\tValid until " + validity.notAfterGMT + "\n");
    }
}

var myListener =
{
    QueryInterface: function(aIID)
    {
        if (aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener) ||
           aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsWeakReference) ||
           aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports))
            return this;
        throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    },

    onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aFlag, aStatus) { },

    onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI) { },

    onProgressChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, curSelf, maxSelf, curTot, maxTot) { },
    onStatusChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStatus, aMessage) { },
    onSecurityChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aState) 
    {
        // check if the state is secure or not
        if(aState & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_SECURE)
        {
            // this is a secure page, check if aRequest is a channel,
            // since only channels have security information
            if (aRequest instanceof Ci.nsIChannel)
            {
                dumpSecurityInfo(aRequest);
            }
        }    
    }
}

var test =
{
    run: function() {
        dump("run\n");
        gBrowser.addProgressListener(myListener);
    }
};

window.addEventListener("load", function () { test.run(); }, false);
```