# How to get server public key (or certificate) from browser when using HTTPS

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, client, certificate

We need to access server public key (or certificate) from browser on client side. When I access HTTPS side, browser downloads server certificate. We need to get this certificate (or public key) to use it in our code on client side (JavaScript) and do with that some cryptographic operations. We are looking for solution without plugin development for browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome).

Are there, for example, some browser specific extensions (JavaScript can detect used browser and call browser specific JavaScript methods accessing certificate), which can help us to read server certificate on client side?

Is this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/b4ffc420-4a7e-450d-90fe-2df60fb25e8d/accessing-the-ssl-server-certificate-of-a-webpage what we can use in IE? If yes, how to use it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604399/is-there-a-way-to-get-ssl-certificate-details-using-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983401/how-can-i-get-the-ssl-certificate-info-for-the-current-page-in-a-firefox-exten

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way, how to do it without browser specific plugins development.